# How do I import pytraj in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am getting the following error when I am tring to import pytaj in python.

ImportError: /home/supriyo/software/amber16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytraj/cpp_options.so: undefined symbol: _Z15SupressErrorMsgb?

Comment: Did you try this: [Get undefined symbol error when import pytraj](http://amber-md.github.io/pytraj/latest/faq.html#get-undefined-symbol-error-when-import-pytraj)?

Comment: Thanks! got it  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that pytraj was linked to the wrong libcpptraj

Try

ldd /home/supriyo/software/amber16/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytraj/cpp_options.so

and delete the libcpptraj.so from that output.

It's better to open and issue in

github.com/amber-md/pytraj